# How do I know when a cow or goat is ready to be milked?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm tired of randomly going up to my cows and goats trying to milk them. Is there any visual or other way to know when my cows or goats are ready to be milked?

Comment: Goats produce milk every other day. I am trying to find some information regarding Cows milk production rates.

Comment: It would appear that Cows can be milked at some point daily whilst Goats are available every two days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no visual indicator. With goats you just have to remember whether it's an even or odd day since they last were milked. With cows they should have milk nearly every day — I've had my first adult cow for just under two seasons and it's given milk all but three or four of those days.